# How to keep url port with proxy_pass in nginx

Tags: nginx

I am trying to use proxy pass to access an image service, however, my nginx container is running on port `8080` and when nginx passes to the service it redirects the user to port `80`.

Here is my nginx snippet:

```
location /api/Image/ {
   proxy_pass http://image.service.com/api/Image?$args;

   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Example of my curl request:

```
➜  .ssh curl -I http://local.docker:8080/api/Image\?urlId\=s4U3y%2FjS%2FPqDJjS%2BQzOjOu4PvCLx8QQQmwd2%2BwTT8C8%3D
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 03 Dec 2018 16:01:18 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Location: http://local.docker/api/Image/?urlId=s4U3y%2FjS%2FPqDJjS%2BQzOjOu4PvCLx8QQQmwd2%2BwTT8C8%3D
Connection: keep-alive
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains;
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
```

My end goal is to add a `jpg` suffix, but my main issue is that I can't work out how to prevent nginx from redirecting to port `80`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on that NGINX block, you will need to request that URL *including* the trailing slash.

The NGINX block will match URLs as follows:

```
/api/Image/foo/bar
/api/Image/
```

But not

```
/api/Image
```

Which is how your cURL command is constructed:

```
curl http://local.docker:8080/api/Image\?urlId\=s4U3y%2FjS%2FPqDJjS%2BQzOjOu4PvCLx8QQQmwd2%2BwTT8C8%3D
```

It's likely the redirect is coming from the default block, and I would guess it's not coming from NGINX at all but rather an upstream proxy.